# Unique pairs of columns SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 4 columns, like below:

```
COL1   COL1_TIME  COL2  COL2_TIME
    A   09:20:00    E   09:35:00
    A   09:20:00    F   09:36:00
    A   09:20:00    G   09:40:00
    A   09:20:00    H   09:59:00
    B   09:25:00    E   09:35:00
    B   09:25:00    F   09:36:00
    B   09:25:00    G   09:40:00
    B   09:25:00    H   09:59:00
    C   09:30:00    E   09:35:00
    C   09:30:00    F   09:36:00
    C   09:30:00    G   09:40:00
    C   09:30:00    H   09:59:00
    D   09:50:00    H   09:59:00
```

I have to select unique pairs of values from columns COL1 and COL2. To find a pair, you should take Closest time to COL1_TIME in COL2_TIME.

So the colsest time for A is E. For B its F - E is taken already etc.

Result should look like this:

```
A E
B F
C G
D H
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this requires recursive CTEs, and I don't think Vertica supports those.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : can you please write the query for sql server

Answer (score 0):

If the cardinality of COL1 and COL2 distinct values is always 1-1 and no other special occasions/exeptions exist, you can do the following:

```
with  temp1 as (

    select col1
          ,col1_time
          ,row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1 desc) as rownum1  

), temp2 as(

    select col2
          ,col2_time
          ,row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2 desc) as rownum2 

)

   select  distinct(temp1.col1)
       ,distinct(temp2.col2) 
   from temp1,temp2    
  where temp1.rownum1 = temp2.rownum2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, without the recursive WITH Common Table Expression, you need to hard-wire a few things.
And if you have more than 4 values for COL1, it gets even more tedious; and if it is about a very important business issue, consider writing a UDx for that.

But - otherwise - here is one that works - input included in the first Common Table Expression of the WITH clause:

```
WITH 
input(col1,col1_time,col2,col2_time) AS (
          SELECT 'A',TIME '09:20:00','E',TIME '09:35:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',TIME '09:20:00','F',TIME '09:36:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',TIME '09:20:00','G',TIME '09:40:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',TIME '09:20:00','H',TIME '09:59:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',TIME '09:25:00','E',TIME '09:35:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',TIME '09:25:00','F',TIME '09:36:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',TIME '09:25:00','G',TIME '09:40:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',TIME '09:25:00','H',TIME '09:59:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',TIME '09:30:00','E',TIME '09:35:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',TIME '09:30:00','F',TIME '09:36:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',TIME '09:30:00','G',TIME '09:40:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C',TIME '09:30:00','H',TIME '09:59:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D',TIME '09:50:00','H',TIME '09:59:00'
)
,
col1_A AS (
SELECT 
  col1
, col2
FROM input
WHERE col1='A'
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF('SECOND',col1_time::TIMESTAMP,col2_time::TIMESTAMP))
LIMIT 1
)
,
col1_B AS (
SELECT 
  col1
, col2
FROM input
WHERE col1='B'
  AND col2 NOT IN (
    SELECT col2 FROM col1_A
  )
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF('SECOND',col1_time::TIMESTAMP,col2_time::TIMESTAMP))
LIMIT 1
)
,
col1_C AS (
SELECT 
  col1
, col2
FROM input
WHERE col1='C'
  AND col2 NOT IN (
              SELECT col2 FROM col1_A 
    UNION ALL SELECT col2 FROM col1_B
  )
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF('SECOND',col1_time::TIMESTAMP,col2_time::TIMESTAMP))
LIMIT 1
)
,
col1_D AS (
SELECT 
  col1
, col2
FROM input
WHERE col1='D'
  AND col2 NOT IN (
              SELECT col2 FROM col1_A 
    UNION ALL SELECT col2 FROM col1_B 
    UNION ALL SELECT col2 FROM col1_C
  )
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF('SECOND',col1_time::TIMESTAMP,col2_time::TIMESTAMP))
LIMIT 1
)
          SELECT * FROM col1_A 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM col1_B 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM col1_C 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM col1_D
;
```

If it's not what you'd hoped for, I'd not be surprised ...

Happy playing ...

Marco the Sane